# Saving values into array

Tags: c++

I have some trouble, saving values from input stream (cin) into an array.

```
int count = 2;
double *startValues = new double[count];
for(int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    double tmpVal;
    cout << i + 1 << ". Startwert: "; cin >> tmpVal;
    startValues[i] = tmpVal;
}
```

After the for loop only the first value is saved in the array startValues, but not the second one. What is wrong here?

Comment: You should be using a `std::vector`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Error checking. You need to verify that you actually *did* read a double from `cin`

```
int count = 2;
double *startValues = new double[count];
int i = 0;
while (i < count) {
    double tmpVal;
    cout << i + 1 << ". Startwert: "; 
    if (cin >> tmpVal) {
      startValues[i] = tmpVal;
      ++i;
    } else {
      cout << "\nIncorrect entry, try again\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: After implementing your version I found my initial error. Did not insert a double value (0.0), but an int (0). Thanks for your help ;)